# EGit (Eclipse) wrongly interpreting file names with non-ASCII characters?

Tags: git, eclipse, encoding, egit

I recently switched to using a Git repository within Eclipse (Juno SR2), using EGit. In our project, some file names contains umlauts and other special non-ASCII-characters. On the command line, `git status` show no changes, workspace clean, but Eclipse marks those files as changed:[image]

How can I make Eclipse/EGit use the correct encoding for filenames? I tried setting `LANG`, `file.encoding` and the `git` config `svn.pathnameencoding` all to no avail. And again, on the command line there are no such errors.

Comment: Did you try setting the workspace encoding to UTF-8? Or whatever the file name encoding is like?

On which OS are you working?

Comment: Did you set any encoding In Window -> Preferences ->General->Content types ? Did you close and then reopen the file after changing the encoding in Window -> Preferences -> Workspace -> Text file encoding ?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Which encoding are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Aptana Git. I prefer that one.

Help > Install New Software > Aptana Studio - http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

It will actually install a great deal of plugins, mostly for web development, but I don't see a way to install the Git plugin separately.

Then go to your project > Navigator > Project > Right Click > Team > Disconnect > Right Click > Team > Share Project > Aptana Git > Next > Finish

This is what the commit screen looks like:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This is indeed a funny answer: If your plugin for the IDE you are using is not working, choose another IDE. BTW: There are people which are using Eclipse for other Development - Tasks rather then Web /JS/ HTML. ;)

Comment: @Peter Glad I could entertain. However, it's a different plugin, not a different IDE.

Comment: So it's integrating good with Eclipse rather then the Aptana Studio which was build on top of Eclipse? And supports latest versions of Eclipse? This questions arise to me when using plugins of Vendors maintaining their own Eclipse - based IDE.

Comment: @Peter Yes Aptana is just another plugin. I'm using latest Eclipse (at the time) Kepler. You can download entire Eclipse from vendors with the plugins pre-installed or vanilla Eclipse and install them manually (which is what I did after Android Developer Kit flaked out and I had to re-install).

Comment: Okay, because I used Aptana Studio standanlone a year ago and wasn't too  satisfied because some of the capabilities related to JS weren't as sophisticated as in Netbeans, e.g..

Comment: So that's why I putted the Git - Plugin into this context and concerned about having issues. But being unsatisfied with EGit, too, perhaps I will give it a try.